# Create several instances of settings

Tags: c#, textbox, settings

I'm about to create an application where I want to measure with and therefore be able to store settings for a large amount of accelerometers. The problem is that I don't know how many at this point, hence I'd like to be able to create a new instance of the accelerometer settings (Name of the accelerometer, frequency range and so forth) for each accelerometer I add to the system. To be able to configure the settings, I've add a ListBox that will show the names of the accelerometers and when clicking on a item in this box the textboxes on the page should be filled with the settings.

...at least that's the theory. Does anyone know how to create an instance of my AccelerometerSettings class based on a string in a textbox? That is, instead of;

```
    AccelerometerSettings SomeRandomAccelerometer = New AccelerometerSettings();
```

I'd like to have

```
    AccelerometerSettings TheNameTypedInTheTextBox = New AccelerometerSettings();
```

for each new accelerometer. Or have I completely misunderstood how the SettingsClass works?

And how do I display all of my accelerometers in the ListBox and make the settings appear in the textbox when clicking?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The example you provide merely modifies the name of a variable. Probably not your intention. You could opt to have an external configuration file that is passed to the AcceleromterSettings constructor based on the type of sensor it is holding settings for. The constructor would then use that file to determine its settings. The configuration file paths could be held in a dictionary with the textBox value as their key, though that would lead to changes in source being required for every new sensor.

Comment: Not really familiar with AccelerometerSettings, but if I had a task to relate a on object to a string I'd be likely using a Dictionary<string, AccelerometerSettings>. There are a few other ways this can be done, but that's the easiest way, i think.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, but I don't quite follow! I already have settings file created with Visual Studios tool. But you mean that I should add some other type of configuration file? If so, what type of configuration file is that and what exactly should I save in that file? And by changes in the source code, do you mean that I have to modify my code for each sensor I add?

Comment: @Eugene: Interesting! Where do I save that Dictionary so that it's stored from session to session? Does your solution mean that as long as I use different string, I can name "AccelerometerSettings" (my settings class) to the same thing?

Comment: @user2950764 I'm not really familiar with mobile development, so not sure about the storage options. You can name your object whatever you want, the name doesn't matter - you're storing the string key, and an object. The key has to be unique.

Comment: @Eugene: I'm not sure what you mean by "mobile development", but this is an application for a DAQ unit to a regular PC. The accelerometers I'm referring to is industrial accelerometers to measure vibrations in machinery :) But I think I get it now, thanks!

Comment: @user2950764 Ah, ok, I googled the AccelerometerSettings and the first thing it came up with was a class from Xamarine, which is mobile development lib. I'm not familiar with DAQ either, though :)

Comment: @Eugene: I realize I wasn't clear with the names here, sorry for that! AccelerometerSettings is just the name of my Class with information about the accelerometer. Whether it's a DAQ or not isn't very relevant at this point, the question is how to create new instances of a "type" of settings at runtime. It could be "add new setting for cow 1, cow 2" and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some basic understanding issues.

AccelerometerSettings TheNameTypedInTheTextBox = New AccelerometerSettings();

Is a c# declaration for a variable of the type AccelerometerSettings that is also initialized to a new object instance.

To maintain a named collection of settings at runtime, you should probably use a collection class.

For example, you could use a dictionary class

```
Dictionary<TKey,TValue>
```

Declare and initialize your dictionary as

```
var MySettings = new Dictionary<string,AccelerometerSettings>();
```

The use the Add() method on MySettings to add a new instance with a name (supplied by the user). The dictionary

Comment: Thanks Gary! Well no doubt about it, I'm fairly new to this kind of programming! My thought was that since I create a new set of settings with the Visual studio tool, to do it manually I'd create new instances of a settings file and just rename it. Your and Eugenes solution seems like a great one, however they raise some new questions. First, how do I store this settings in an easy way so that the settings remain from session to session? Do I have to read in all this settings at the startup, or are they stored automatically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2950764 You'll probably want to create a new question for that, and mark/upvote answers you like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic, naive implementation of something that would achieve close to what you're looking for. It could be vastly improved, but it should set you on the right track.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class SettingsManager
{
    Dictionary<string, AcceleromterSettings> settings;

    // contructor for SettingsManager class; a fundamental C# concept
    public SettingsManager()
    {
        LoadSettings();
    }

    // creates new instances of AccelerometerSettings and stores them
    // in a Dictionary<key, value> object for later retrieval. The
    // Dictionary object uses a unique-key to access a value
    // which can be any object.
    void LoadSettings()
    {
        settings = new Dictionary<string, AcceleromterSettings>();

        AcceleromterSettings horizontal = new AcceleromterSettings();
        horizontal.AttributeOne = 101;
        horizontal.AttributeTwo = 532;
        horizontal.AttributeThree = 783;
        settings.Add("Horizontal", horizontal);

        AcceleromterSettings vertical = new AcceleromterSettings();
        vertical.AttributeOne = 50;
        vertical.AttributeTwo = 74;
        vertical.AttributeThree = 99;
        settings.Add("Vertical", vertical);
    }

    // Retrieves settings from the Dictionary while hiding
    // specific implementation details.
    public AcceleromterSettings GetSettings(string name)
    {
        AcceleromterSettings setting = null;

        // this method of Dictionary returns a Boolean value indicating
        // whether or not the value retrieval worked. If the Key is found
        // in the dictionary, the 'out' parameter is modified reflect
        // the value, and the method returns true. If the key is not found
        // the 'out' parameter is not modified, and the method returns false.
        if (!settings.TryGetValue(name, out setting))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Settings not found for settings name {0}", name));

        return setting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Just some questions though, what does the SettingsManager() method and LoadSettings do? Read all the settings at startup? What's with the setting = null; in GetSettings(), as I see it just returns null?

Comment: @user2950764 See edits. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Again @Michael, many thanks! I get a lot of strange errors though, something about "The type 'Program.AccelerometerSettings' already contains a defenition for 'defaultInstance' (a variable I've never created nor used) and the same for pretty much all the attributes I try to add. When I double-click at the errors, I get to the auto-generated code. Any idea what this is about?

Comment: I'm not sure about why the errors above occurred, but I deleted the file and created a new one and now I don't seem to have any problems at all.